# IllegalStateException No LoadTimeWeaver available

Tags: spring, tomcat, aspectj, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to get load time working in a Tomcat server defined inside STS.

I've added the load time weaver to the application context:

context:load-time-weaver/>

(I've tried as well)

context:load-time-weaver weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>

The project contains the required jars (spring-aop.jar, aspectjweaver.jar) and the instrument jar has been copied to the tomcat/lib (spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar).

The context.xml inside the Servers project contains:

```
<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
```

(I've tried in the tomcat/conf/context.xml and in the META-INF/context.xml as well)

When I start the server I get the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoadTimeWeaver available"

Stepping in AspectJWeavingEnabler:enableAspectJWeaving, the method that throws the exception, the bean class loader has been correctly instantiated to TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader, but the LoadTimeWeaver is null. I believe the LoadTimeWeaver should have been injected by the application context "context:load-time-weaver". The instantiated TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader seems to suggest that both the spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar and the loaderClass entry in the context.xml have been correctly picked up.

Comment: I believe the crux is in the fact that you use Tomcat inside STS (or Eclipse for that matter). Not sure what to do about it. If you have a recent version of Tomcat you don't need to add the spring-instrumentation jar anymore it should be enough to do `<context:load-time-weaver />`. Tomcat version greater as 7.0.43 have a new classloader which allows for easier LTW. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10788

Comment: To verify the sts/rad/eclipse theory I've deployed the war in apache-tomcat-7.0.52 standalone. I've tried with and without the spring-instrumentation. Same result:"java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoadTimeWeaver available". So it looks like it's not eclipse. Could it be some aspect trying to weave before spring has completed its configuration?

Comment: Have you tried with a plain `<context:load-time-weaver />` element? Works as expected here.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the plain <context:load-time-weaver /> element as well. Same error. I wonder if it could have something to do with our spring (3.2.5) or tomcat (7.0.52) versions.

Comment: If you are using Spring 3.2.5 then why are you using the instrumentation jar of Spring 4.0.2 never mix jars of different spring versions!? The latter let me believe you where using Spring 4! With Spring 3.2.x you still have to add the instrumented classloading yourself.

Comment: Yes, I saw about the 4.0.2 in your link, that's why I was using the context.xml and the jar. You are right, dumb mistake with the 4.0.2 version! Somehow I though the instrumentation jar was in a independent version branch. Unfortunately I did replace spring-instrument-tomcat 4.0.2 with 3.2.5, and got the same error (tear).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue right now. How did you solve this ?